# Import two images : one compressed the other not

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want my users being able to upload photos. Then, I want to display a compressed image to load quicker and the full-size image when they click on the compressed one.
For this, I think I have to upload two different photos. This is how I upload the uncompressed one :

```
if(!$_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE){
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$name = md5(session_id().microtime()) . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target_file = $target_dir . $name;//basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "<br />Image détectée - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "<br />Le fichier n'est pas une image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "<br />Le fichier existe déjà, renommez le et réessayez.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
    echo "<br />L'image est trop lourde, compressez-la ou réduisez sa taille.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "<br />Seul les formats JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF sont autorisés.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "<br />Le fichier n'a pas été importé.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "<br />L'image a été importée.";

        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO spots(nom, description, img1, latitude, longitude, pseudoCreateur, idCreateur) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $req->execute(array($_POST['nom'], $description, $name, $_POST['latitude'], $_POST['longitude'], $_SESSION['pseudo'], $_SESSION['id']));

        $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT points FROM users WHERE id = ?');
        $req->execute(array($_SESSION['id']));
        $points = $req->fetch();

        $bdd->exec('UPDATE users SET points = ' . (string)($points[0] + 3) .' WHERE id = '. $_SESSION['id']);
        echo "<br /><br />SPOT PUBLIÉ !";

    } else {
        echo "<br />Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

How can I upload a compressed image ?

EDIT :
Solved using : [VEROT](https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php)

Comment: Please define 'compressed'. Is the number of pixels just smaller, or are we talking real data compression? So, please specify 'compression' exactly.

Comment: I mean reduce the number of pixels. Sorry for my bad English, I am French

Comment: You could resize the original image with `imagescale()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php Example usage: http://www.ajarunthomas.com/tutorials/php/resize-an-image-in-php-using-the-gd-library (uses `imagecopyresampled()`, but that is very similar)

Comment: `I mean reduce …` Don't comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: edit your question. `Sorry for …, I am…` Never apologise for what you are: exercise due care, try and avoid errors, especially repeating them - ignore anyone asking for more. `…French` the messages in the code presented are in more than one language.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I tried  `imagescale()` but it expect the parameter to be a ressource while `move_uploaded_file()` expects a String, how can I solve this ?